Logback roll over log files based on size not working
I have below config and its rolling policy is working to keep the file to max of 5 files.
But the triggering policy is getting triggered on random file sizes for rotation.
Not rotating on the exact size mentioned in 
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FOLDER}/old.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
    <minIndex>1</minIndex>
    <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
</rollingPolicy>

<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
    <maxFileSize>5000000</maxFileSize>
</triggeringPolicy>

<encoder>
    <Pattern>${FILE_PATTERN}</Pattern>
</encoder>


Hi, how much "random" are the file sizes? Remember that the file splitting may not occurr in the middle of a logging line, so if your current file size il 4999999 and the application logs a 1000 characters line, the final size of the splitted file would be 5000999, not exactly 5000000.

Why do you use a triggereringPolicy instead of setting maxFileSize in the rollingPolicy?
